# Find equation of line that separates two Classes in SVM

Tags: svm, linear-algebra

[image]

[image]

Hence, $w_1=w_2 = -.5$ and $b=7/2$.

I'm confused as to how we know that $w_1=w_2$ from $x_1+x_2=7$?

Comment: Can you relate the equations $x_1+x_2=7$ and $(w_1,w_2)\cdot(x_1,x_2) + 7/2 = 0$?

Comment: what if I don't know that b = 7/2?Second, yes, I can. But I get the wrong answer. I get $w_1=w_2$ = 1 and $b=-7$.

Comment: Divide by $-2$.